# TStream with Datasnap Rest and Close-session

Tags: rest, delphi, session, datasnap

I build a datasnap REST application and I can't close the session.

For example if I call my URL 4 times in my web browser:
`http://127.0.0.1:4445/REST/image?json=false`

There is 4 sessions opened.

Here is my function:

```
function TV1.TestImage:TStream;
var
ContentType : String;
FileStream : TFileStream;
begin
    FileStream := TFileStream.Create('C:\santiago.jpg', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
    ContentType := 'image/jpg';

    GetInvocationMetadata.ResponseContentType := ContentType;
    ContentTypeHeaderToUse := ContentType;
    GetInvocationMetadata().ResponseCode := 200;

    result := FileStream;

    //Can't call CloseSession with TStream, pointer exception
    //GetInvocationMetaData.CloseSession := True;

end;
```

And I use the `WebModuleAfterDispatch` like that:

```
  procedure TWebModule2.WebModuleAfterDispatch(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
  var session : TDSSession;
  begin
      response.FreeContentStream := true;

      if ContentTypeHeaderToUse<>'' then begin
          Response.ContentType := ContentTypeHeaderToUse;
          ContentTypeHeaderToUse := ''; // Reset global variable
      end;

  end;
```

As you can see, `GetInvocationMetaData.CloseSession := True;` can't be used here.

Do you know how to close session after sending the TStream?

Comment: Do you really need to have sessions ?. It looks like that you should have the Lifecycle property of your DSServerClass to Server or Invocation.

Comment: I tried to put my DSServerClass to server and Invocation and I have the same issues, the sessions number is increased. I don't need sessions for my application. From the other URL I don't have this issue, it's just with the TStream.

Comment: How do you check the number of active sessions ?. With Lifecycle as Server there are no sessions, so that result has to be wrong. Anyway, are you sure that you want to return a Stream on a REST server ?, how does your client manage to understand that Stream (it is returned as an array of bytes, isn't it ?). On a very similar situation, I return an string, with the base64 representation of your stream content. It's easier for your client application to deal with a base64 string, and there are no objects left open to be dealt by the Datasnap mechanic.

Comment: It's true, I get an array of byte after the TSTream call. To show active sessions, I use `TDSSessionManager.Instance.GetSessionCount` in a timer event, the sessions increase in lifecycle server, in the documentation they said than the invocation and session are the same for a Rest app. In the past, we returned an ansiString but we encountered too many issues with the picture display that pixelated. This issue occured when we changed delphi to 10.2, some of the byte from the returned ansistring were changed after the call. Is base64 compatible with recent web browser?(IE, Edge, Chrome, Firefox)

Comment: Yes, we use directly the returned base64 string to show the images on IE, Edge, Chrome and Firefox. As far as I know, we have never encountered any problem with them. About the Sessions problem, I'm sorry, I cannot help you, I have never faced this problem.

Comment: You only need to include the type at the start of your <img> tag. It should result in something like : <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABkAAA.........=">

Answer (score 1):

On a REST server I prefer to return a base64 string, it's easier to deal for the client app than the JSON representation of a Delphi TStream (an array of bytes).

The EncodeBase64 function on the Soap.EncdDecd unit does the transformation very easily :

```
function TV1.TestImage:string;
var MemoryStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  MemoryStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  MemoryStream.LoadFromFile('C:\santiago.jpg');
  Result := EncodeBase64(MemoryStream.Memory, MemoryStream.Size);
  MemoryStream.Free; // Now you can free the Stream yourself
end;
```

An additional benefit is that you can now release your Stream and not depend on Datasnap doing it. So you should be able to manually close your connection without that pointer exception and solve the problem of multiple sessions remaining open.

You can directly use that base64 image string on your web application. You only need to add their type at the start of an < img > tag.

Example :

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
```